# Glassfish 3.1.2 will not load

Tags: glassfish

JDeveloper 12.1.3.0.0
Glasfish 3.1.2
JSF/JSP bc4j

Deploying our application ( originaly developed in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7) for the first time to Glassfish fails with the below entry in the log. I have tried to compile (and run Glassfish) on Java 6 & 7. That makes no difference.

The application deploys and loads ok in JDeveloper Weblogic built in.

Any ideas?

ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly. at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109) at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130) at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269) at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240) at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:321) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.post(TemplateListOfResource.java:180) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly. at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366) ... 63 more Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly. at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305) at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) ... 66 more Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactoryImpl at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:630) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:509) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:139) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:993) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343) at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303) ... 69 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:623) ... 74 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/util/ClassLoaderUtils at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.AdfExceptionHandlerUtils.getExceptionHandlers(AdfExceptionHandlerUtils.java:24) at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactoryImpl.(ExceptionHandlerFactoryImpl.java:19) ... 79 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util.ClassLoaderUtils at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509) at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359) ... 81 more

Best regards

Erik

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <description>Empty web.xml file for Web Application</description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If this parameter is true, there will be an automatic check of the modification date of your JSPs, and saved state will be discarded when JSP's change. It will also automatically check if your skinning css files have changed without you having to restart the server. This makes development easier, but adds overhead. For this reason this parameter should be set to false when your application is deployed.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Whether the 'Generated by...' comment at the bottom of ADF Faces HTML pages should contain version number information.</description>
        <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.versionString.HIDDEN</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY</param-name>
        <param-value>4512000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD_MAX_DISK_SPACE</param-name>
        <param-value>45120000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>/home/oracle/ADFUploads/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Security precaution to prevent clickjacking: bust frames if the ancestor window domain(protocol, host, and port) and the frame domain are different. Another options for this parameter are always and never.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING</param-name>
        <param-value>differentOrigin</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enable.anonymous</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>adfBindings</filter-name>
        <filter-class>oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>adfBindings</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BIGRAPHSERVLET</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.graph.GraphServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BIGAUGESERVLET</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.gauge.GaugeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MapProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.geoMap.servlet.MapProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GatewayServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.graph.FlashBridgeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <!--
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hrsusui.backing.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BIGRAPHSERVLET</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/GraphServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BIGAUGESERVLET</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/GaugeServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MapProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mapproxy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GatewayServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/flashbridge/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/imageservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>35</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>swf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-shockwave-flash</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/welcome.jspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsff</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
            <is-xml>true</is-xml>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group> 
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deploying our application"?  What actual actions did you perform that resulted in this error?

Comment: From within JDeveloper I choose the menu "Application" and from there "Deploy".

Comment: Please update the question with your `web.xml` and if it is a maven project your `pom.xml`.

Comment: The solution was to exclude 2 jar files (both named *security* from deplyment in GUI project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to exclude 2 jar files (both named security from deplyment in GUI project.